# How do I get rid of a caged goblin?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I managed to catch a goblin in a cage and now he is just sitting at the entryway to my fortress. I have tried disarming him with <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> with a garbage dump zone nearby but my dwarves just ignore him.

I have tried throwing him into my pit (which is my ultimate goal) but, again, dwarves just happily walk by ignoring him.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say by the description alone, but did you check that your dwarves are actually allowed to collect garbage from the outside, have a valid garbage dump zone they can use, and can path between the two (including zone restrictions)? The cage *might* be just outside, depending on how you built your entryway. A picture or two of the situation might be helpful.

Comment: Did you designate a animal stockpile for the cage? That could be what is stopping the haulers.

Comment: Are your dorfs busy?

Comment: Is the cage or its contents forbidden?

Comment: Do your dwarves have the animal hauling labour enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments said, he could be outside so you need to enable outside collection of refuse but I don't think that's the problem because I don't think it's seen as refuse.

The way you move a prisoner is you have to make a new cage in the location you want him to be, then you go into the properties of that cage and set the goblin to it.

The dwarfs will then grab the goblin by the arm and lead him to the next cage.

Have your military ready in the next room. I think there was some rule that goblins can't get away from a dwarf leading them somewhere, but just to be safe have the dorfs nearby.

Comment: Goblin *soldiers* don't usually try to escape, though the Dwarf escorting the goblin might suddenly decide it's time to take a nap, or drink some bear, and just walk away (... and panic after he or she realised there is a free goblin running around!). Goblin thieves (which is more likely in his case, since there's only one) can and do try to escape.

Comment: You can construct the cage that the goblin's in. When selecting the type of cage to construct (after choosing the location), hit *x* to see a list of individual cages that can be built. One should say "goblin cage" or the goblin's name. Even if it isn't named, you can view the item in detail to see its contents.

Comment: @MartinSojka: [Drinking bear](http://i.imgur.com/btjbX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem - it looks like from the wiki you have to setup a situation that will lead to it's death, then release it from the cage. You can't just tell your soldiers to kill it, butcher it, etc.

http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Captured_creatures